# Running a web-spider on Java

Tags: java, windows, web, web-crawler, heritrix

Launch web spider on Windovs 8.1 64-bit. Tried not to connect additional libraries, and eventually climbs mistake.

```
C:\Users\I>cd c:\Users\i\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4

c:\Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4>cd bin

c:\Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\bin>heritrix.cmd
You have to specify either a username and password for the
web interface or start Heritrix without the web ui.

Example: heritrix.cmd --admin=admin:letmein
         heritrix.cmd --nowui myOrder.xml

c:\Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\bin>extractor
Error: Password file not found: \Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\jmxremote.password

c:\Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\bin>heritrix.cmd
You have to specify either a username and password for the
web interface or start Heritrix without the web ui.

Example: heritrix.cmd --admin=admin:letmein
         heritrix.cmd --nowui myOrder.xml

c:\Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\bin>
```

What and where should I enter the password and login?

Comment: c:\Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\bin>heritrix --admin=LOGIN:PASSWORD
WARNING: It's currently not possible to run Heritrix in background
         on Windows. It was just started minimized in a new Window
         and will be shut down as soon as you log off.

10.12.2013 16:13:09,88 Starting heritrix

Heritrix failed to start properly. Possible causes:

- Login and password have not been specified (see --admin switch)
- another program uses the port for the web UI (8080 by default)
  (e.g. another Heritrix instance)
- JMX password file is missing or permissions not set correctly

Comment: JMX permissions file missing. A template can be found in
  \Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\conf\jmxremote.password.template.
Copy it to
  \Users\I\Desktop\heritrix-1.14.4\jmxremote.password
and edit the passwords at the end of the file. Then, make sure
the file is read-restricted to only the user that the Heritrix
Java VM will run as.

Answer (score 0):

try simply

```
heritrix --admin=LOGIN:PASSWORD
```